# How to ignore Pyflakes errors ‘imported but unused’ in ‘__init__.py’ files?

Tags: python, import, lint, pyflakes

I split my tests across multiple Python files:

```sh
tests
├── __init__.py
├── test_apples.py
└── test_bananas.py.py
```

I import the tests in the ‘__init__.py’ file:

```py
from test_apples import ApplesTest
from test_bananas import BananasTest
```

However running Pyflakes on the command-line:

```sh
pyflakes .
```

outputs the following errors:

```sh
tests/__init__.py:1: [E] PYFLAKES:'ApplesTest' imported but unused
tests/__init__.py:2: [E] PYFLAKES:'BananasTest' imported but unused
```

Comment: It isn't an error, it's just information that you have unused imports. There isn't any problem with it.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Add `# pyflakes.ignore` comment on every line you want to ignore (in your case  import statements).

Comment: @user1004669 And it shouldn't. You have imports in `__init__.py`. You don't use them in `__init__.py`. That's what PYFLAKES is telling you. Now it's up to you to decide what to do with it. There is no problem here. So you should do nothing. If you still have some doubts check any well-known project and I sure you will get the same message.

Comment: @DrTysa - The messages are annoying and distract from writing good code. They also make it more difficult to see actual useful messages from pyflakes.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as a correct answer, the statement `# pyflakes.ignore` isn't working.

Answer (score 127):

To ignore all errors F401 (‘imported but unused’) in ‘__init__.py’ files, the option [‘per-file-ignores’](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=per-file-ignores#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores) which has been available since version 3.7.0 of [Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) (a better Pyflakes) is very convenient. It can be used on the command-line:

```sh
flake8 --per-file-ignores="__init__.py:F401" .
```

or in a configuration file (‘.flake8’, ‘setup.cfg’ or ‘tox.ini’):

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores = __init__.py:F401
```

Comment: This solution deserves some love as it is perfectly scoped: one issue in one file type. 
Added the following code snippet to `.flake8rc` and it works like a champ.  
```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    __init__.py:F401
```

Comment: I had some quotation issues in VS Code settings.  Just in case, the quotes need to be escaped, as so:

    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--per-file-ignores=\"__init__.py:F401\""
    ],

Comment: Works beautifully in VSCode's Flake Args, just pasted `--per-file-ignores="__init__.py:F401"` there and voila.

Comment: How would one use this with pylama / pyflakes in the `pyalama.ini` config file. All the flavors I tried did not work. I would like to ignore all unused imports in `__init__.py` files. The only thing that worked was adding `# noqa` to each line I would like to ignore.

Comment: python > linting > flake8 args > add item

`per-file-ignores = __init__.py:F401`

without quotes works fine in vscode :)

Comment: years after first upvoting this reply, I wish i could do it again.

Comment: I'd previously upvoted @David Mendes response, but as of March 2023, i believe the quotes are required in the VS Code settings, as Julio Silva's comment indicates.

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes you have to skip a line.
According to the current versions docs (flake8 2.4.1)
The files that contain

```
# flake8: noqa
```

are skipped. This works, and # noga, # pyflakes.ignore not.

Answer (score 15):

In my version of [PyFlakes (0.7.3)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes/0.7.3), using `__all__` works.

Additionally, to skip a line, you should add `# noqa`.

Comment: If you are not sure what `__all__` means, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079047/python-pep8-class-in-init-imported-but-not-used/49266468

Comment: Does using `__all__` make sense when I do only explicit imports inside `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 8):

add `# noqa: F401` to the end of your line (`F401` is a code of this error)

Example:
`from django.utils import http  # noqa: F401`

Answer (score 3):

The imports are interpreted as being unused because your linting tool doesn't understand how it's being used.

The most comprehensive fix is to ensure that these names are clearly *exported* from your module.  Either by setting `__all__`, which is a mechanism for exhaustively enumerating the exported names, or by giving the imports explicit exported names using `as`.

```py
from test_apples import ApplesTest as ApplesTest
```

However, I would generally recommend using a test runner that scans for test cases rather than importing them all, as that gives you more confidence that you're definitely running all of your tests.

Comment: The redundant `from foo import x as x` import is the recommended solution in PEP 484 and [`pyright`](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/856#issuecomment-763793949).