# python pep8 class in init imported but not used

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I'm doing PEP8 checks in python using the python [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) library. I have an import statement in an `__init__.py` file in one of my sub-modules which looks like this:

```
from .my_class import MyClass
```

The reason I have this line in the init file is so that I can import MyClass from the sub-module as `from somemodule import MyClass` instead of having to write `from somemodule.my_class import MyClass`.

I would like to know if it is possible to maintain this functionality while correcting the PEP8 violation?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

This is not actually a PEP8 violation. I simply do this:

```
from .my_class import MyClass  # noqa
```

Edit: Another possibility is to use `__all__`. In that case, flake8 understands what is going on:

```
from .my_class import MyClass

__all__ = ['MyClass',]
```

Answer (score 65):

According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should include `MyClass` in [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python), which will also fix the imported-but-not-used issue:

> To better support introspection, modules should explicitly declare the
>   names in their public API using the __all__ attribute.

Answer (score 21):

According to [flake8's documention](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/stable/user/violations.html#in-line-ignoring-errors), you can in-line ignore this specific warning with:

```
from .my_class import MyClass  # noqa: F401
```

For reference, here are flake8's [error codes](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/stable/user/error-codes.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use flake8 per-file ignore: https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores

- use command line option `flake8 --per-file-ignores='__init__.py:F401`
- or add this to `setup.cfg`, `tox.ini` or `.flake8` file:

  ```ini
  [flake8]
  per-file-ignores =
      # imported but unused
      __init__.py: F401
  ```