# importing modules and populating __all__ in __init__.py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, python-packaging

I am checking the scikit-learn repository in GitHub to understand how this package is organised. I noticed in all sub-packages (and the main package) `__init__.py` file contains a set of `import` statements and then all those modules (that have been imported earlier) are assigned to `__all__`. (For instance, take a look at [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/metrics/**init**.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py))

I know that by importing a packages (sub-package) all instructions in `__init__.py` are executed, and all modules indicated in `__all__` list are imported. So, I cannot understand why all the packages that have already been imported are also assigned in `__all__`. It seems redundant to me. It would be great if someone can clarify this to me (for example, what would happen if we remove `__all__` from `__init__.py` file in the example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/what-does-all-mean-in-python

Comment: @CristiFatiI I know what `__all__` means in `__init__.py`. I do not  understand why in the `__init__.py` files in scikit-learn, modules are imported and then the same modules are assigned to `__all__`

Comment: Re-read your question and I think I understand it now. scikit-learn's [coding guidelines](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/develop.html#coding-guidelines) make an offhand reference to Pyflakes. [This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085245/3004881) might be the reason.

Comment: Indeed, it satisfies the linter's question "why are you importing this but not using it"?  In the case of listing an imported name in `__all__` it's a valid "use" of the import.